# Can the convex hull be characterised as an intersection of half-spaces?

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-hulls

The **convex hull** $[X]$ of a set $X \subset \mathbb R^d$ is the set of all convex combinations $$[X] = \left\{a_1 x_1 + \ldots + a_n x_n: x_i \in X, a_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1\right\}$$ of elements of $X$. The **closed convex hull** $\langle X \rangle$ is the intersection of all closed half spaces that contain $X$. I wonder is there a corresponding notion of half-space for the first definition.

> Is there a family $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $\mathbb R^d$ such that each $[X] = \bigcap   \{C: C \in \mathcal F: X \subset C\}?$

The answer is yes. Just take $\mathcal F$ as the collection of convex sets. This is not satisfying however so let's consider some candidates.

First let $\mathcal F_1$ be the collection of open half-spaces. The condition does not hold because of the counterexample $X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y < 0\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$. Then $X$ is convex but the $\mathcal F_1$-hull is easily seen to be the lower half-plane.

Two more ideas are the following:

> (2) Given an open half-space $P \subset \mathbb R^d$ and corresponding closed half-space $\overline P$ we call any set $Q$ with $P \subset Q \subset \overline P$ a **half-space**. Let $\mathcal F_2$ be the family of half-spaces.

The counterexample no longer works for  $\mathcal F_2$.

> (3) For any $a \in \mathbb R^d$ we say a convex set $X$ is  $a$-maximal to mean $a \notin X$ and $X$ is not properly contained in a convex subset that does not contain $a$. Let $\mathcal F_3$ be all the convex sets that are $a$-maximal wrt some $a$.

I think the elements of  $\mathcal F_3$ can be described as follows. Take an open half-space tangent to $a$. Look at the boundary and take an open $(d-1)$ dimensional half spac tangent to $a$. Look in the boundary of that half-space and proceed until you run out of dimensions.

Clearly $\mathcal F_3$ is more restrictive than  $\mathcal F_2$ but the counterexample still fails. Just take the intersection of $\{y < 0\} \cup \{y=0$ and $x<\epsilon\}$ and $\{y < 0\} \cup \{y=0$ and $x<-\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

I wonder do either of these families induce the usual convex hull definition?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Convex. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't set $X$ be finite?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : I don't believe it needs to be -- does some part of the definition break down if $X$ is infinite?

Comment: The way you defined $[X]$, you seem to have assumed that $X$ is finite.